# ECU Problems Corsa comfort 1.4 2001 auto

Tags: electronic-control-module, security, code

I have a Corsa 1.4 that starts and stops and starts after a break.  Sometimes not at all.  Cranks. After replacing crankshaft sensor, relays on the advice of the RAC who brought me home twice and having it checked by a mechanic, we have come to the conclusion that there's a problem with the ECU.  The fuel pump etc are all good and when it goes it's great.  We did get a code that said something about the identification not recognised or not matched (sorry my memory is poop and I don't have a fault reader),  other faults that came up were fuel pump relay 0230 (showing active when ignition on on obd) and 1616 and 1482 fan 2 (relay replaced) and although these are working fine the codes remain.  so I assume someone has replaced the ECU and not paired it and it is giving false readings or the ECU is mashed. Another clue is that the key doesn't work remotely and although a Vauxhall key it has been well mashed where people have prised it open.  Also the radio is missing.
1.  So if it's the ECU, do people think an opcom would solve this and/or a scrap ECU kit. 
2. Or would just an ECU do the job.
3. Could I disable the immobiliser with opcom.

I say that as at 59 and after two years of driving lessons I finally passed two weeks ago and have obviously been sod a real problem.  I have very little funds.  I am learning a lot about cars though.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I do not have any access in my [USA] databases for your particular vehicle.

*However*, the symptoms you describe seem to point to an "immobilizer" type function.

I tend to doubt the ECU is at fault.  I more suspect your "mashed" key fob.  Has the battery in the fob been replaced recently?

I would start with a new (or refurb) key fob that has been correctly matched to your vehicle.  This will be far cheaper than swapping in a new ECU - which will *still* have to be matched to your keys, vehicle, and security.

Comment: There is no radio/stereo either.  Would this affect it?  Amazingly a mechanic friend who couldn't find what was wrong checked the new crankshaft sensor and amazingly the engine ran for ten mins without it, leading him to think the electrics have been messed with.